# Old pre 2013 PeoplePicker and the new ClientPeoplePicker: do they require different tagging?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

Simple and fast question here: are we using the same tag [people-picker](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people-picker) for both the old PeoplePicker and the new ClientPeoplePicker? 
This came to mind after reading the question 
[SharePoint - How to clear PeoplePicker field with button click?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174246/sharepoint-how-to-clear-peoplepicker-field-with-button-click) - some users actually didn't notice that the question is about the new control, and as you can see the solution is different depending on which control you use.

Are there any preferred community standard at handling situations like this one? Should we create two different tags or one is enough to encompass both controls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they should, 2010/2007/2003 (can't recall) use a different type of field, even though they are the same field. I'd say create a tag, ClientPeoplePicker with a description that it is 2013/2016 specific.

If we are going to differentiate on product versions, we should be able to have version specific tags for aspects that are functionally different but exist and named the same in both platforms.